# Адаптация слайдера между блоками при ресайзе

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, слайдер

Есть картинка макбука, которая располагается на границе синего и белого блоков. Внутри картинки макбука располагается слайдер. При ресайзе слайдер выскакивает из макбука. 
Как сделать, чтоб при любой ширине окна браузера слайдер всегда находился внутри экрана макбука?
[Посмотреть код можно тут.](https://codepen.io/carboncheg/pen/PowMZKL)

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/carboncheg/pen/PowMZKL
```

[Полную реализацию в сети можно глянуть тут.](https://business-landing.website.yandexcloud.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так делается это но всё же скажу что выкладывать надо сюда а не в codepen и выкладывать только то что относится к вопросу ...

```js
function slider() {

  let slideIndex = 1,
    slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider_item'),
    prev = document.querySelector('.prev'),
    next = document.querySelector('.next'),
    dotsWrapper = document.querySelector('.dots_wrapper'),
    dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot'),
    slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function showSlides(n) {

    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
    }

    slides.forEach((item) => item.style.display = 'none');

    dots.forEach((item) => item.classList.remove('dot_active'));

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
    dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('dot_active');
  }

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    plusSlides(1);
  });

  prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
    plusSlides(-1);
  });

  dotsWrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= dots.length; i++) {
      if (event.target.classList.contains('dot') &&
        event.target == dots[i - 1]) {
        currentSlide(i);
        clearInterval(timerId);
        autoshow();
      }
    }
  });

  let timerId;

  function autoshow() {
    timerId = setInterval(() => plusSlides(1), 2000);
  }
  autoshow();
  slider.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  });

  slider.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
    autoshow();
  });
}
slider();
```

```css
.slider-section {}

.slider-wrapper {
  width: 645px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(https://business-landing.website.yandexcloud.net/img/macbook.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slider img {
  width: 445px;
  height: 248px;
}

.dots_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.dot {
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #dedfe0;
}

.dot_active {
  border: 2px solid #1ca8dd;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-section">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slider_item">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6HVCyCq/meetup-0.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider_item">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1K6DBkq/meetup-1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider_item">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/z8WK0sk/meetup-2.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prev">
      <div class="arrow_left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
      <div class="arrow_right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--wrapper-->

  <div class="dots_wrapper">
    <div class="dot dot_active"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Далее медиа запросы ...

Я сделал обёртку и ей дал как фон ваш mackbook и внутри находятся картинки то есть slider и всё

Нажмите **Показать код** -> **Выполнить**